# Next JS 13 app cannot deploy to Azure Static Web Apps

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-web-app-service, next.js13

I am trying to deploy my next 13 app directory application to Azure Static Web Apps, but it returns a 500 error when I go to the url. I can't see any logs on Azure, I couldn't find them under the Diagnose tab. My workflow file looks like this:

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - master
    pull_request:
        types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
        branches:
            - master

jobs:
    build_and_deploy_job:
        if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        name: Build and Deploy Job
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v3
              with:
                  submodules: true
            - name: Build And Deploy
              id: builddeploy
              uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
              with:
                  azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ORANGE_DUNE_0B46C9510 }}
                  repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
                  action: "upload"
                  ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
                  # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
                  app_location: "/" # App source code path
                  api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
                  output_location: "" # Built app content directory - optional
                  app_build_command: "npm run build"
                  api_build_command: "rm -rf ./node_modules/@next/swc-* && rm -rf ./.next/cache"
                  ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

    close_pull_request_job:
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        name: Close Pull Request Job
        steps:
            - name: Close Pull Request
              id: closepullrequest
              uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
              with:
                  azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ORANGE_DUNE_0B46C9510 }}
                  action: "close"
```

The npm run build command is next build and npm run start is next start. I am not using next export cause it cannot be used with i18. What can I in order to successfully deploy to the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Firstly, I have created a Next-js-app @13v in my environment.

[image]

- Created a new repository on GitHub to host the Next.js app's source code and pushed the Application to the remote origin.

[image]

- Then Created a Static web application in portal and linked it with my GitHub repository.

[image]

Here is my `Yaml` code, Check below.

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Build And Deploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "public"
          api_location: ""
          output_location: ""
          app_build_command: "npm run start"
          api_build_command: ""
          skip_deploy_on_missing_secrets: true

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
          action: "close"
          app_location: "public"
          api_location: ""
          output_location: ""
          app_build_command: "npm run start"
          api_build_command: ""
```

- Iam able to build and deploy my applications.

[image]

**Result :**
[image]

Comment: I am getting this error for the yml: 
Failed to find a default file in the app artifacts folder (/). Valid default files: index.html,Index.html.
If your application contains purely static content, please verify that the variable 'app_location' in your workflow file points to the root of your application.
If your application requires build steps, please validate that a default file exists in the build output directory.

Comment: Verify and check that your `app_location` parameter in your workflow file is correctly set to the root directory of your application. this is my Example [path](https://i.imgur.com/E93Zbq3.png) directory.